# Why is the built-in array subscript can be an lvalue?

Tags: c++

[image]

Indicate in cppreference that the expression representing the subscript must be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type.

So why can a for loop that traverses a built-in array, which beginners have learned, be compiled.

such as:

```
int a[10] = {0};
// as we know ,i is a lvalue
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << a[i] << std:endl;
}
```

Comment: Why *not?* Do you have something against variables as indices?

Comment: An lvalue can be converted (implicitly) to an rvalue.

Comment: There is [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Value_transformations).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/10871073) a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With arrays, why is it the case that a\[5\] == 5\[a\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: You completely answered my question. I didn't think about implicit conversion at all. @Jarod42 
 Also, I don't think this is a repetitive problem, which can provide some directions for some newcomers to consider similar problems.

Comment: Please copy and paste all that as formatted text instead of an image. I know it's a pain, but there are [plenty of good reasons for not using screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indicate in cppreference that the expression representing the subscript must be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type.
>
> ```
> // as we know ,i is a lvalue
> ```
>
> So why can a for loop that traverses a built-in array, which beginners have learned, be compiled.

A glvalue expression may be implicitly converted to prvalue with lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.